# fbcdn An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: ios, facebook, avfoundation

Some videos uploaded to facebook using iOS Facebook SDK give me the error "An error occurred while processing your request"

Checkout this [fbcdn video](http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-snc4/344314/981/126804007417160_9376.mp4?oh=decad1db3580ee6adca9e246bb1a970e&oe=4E60F300&__gda__=1314976512_ddb82b55cb8f3d9f1e3be369f02b427a)

I'm trying to play that video on a MPMoviePlayerViewController. Some videos work fine, some videos just don't. The video plays just fine on Facebook, so it's not something related to its data.
Can't find any documentation about what this error is related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the link to the video is expired, usually it works for a 2 days period then it gets expired and you have to query the facebook graph API again to get a new link.

Comment: Do you have any documentation links?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this error page too, on the iOS on an iPhone 4 when using the Facebook app.

To play the video even if it comes up expired, locate the post you want and instead of tapping on the embedded video, choose the post date. If the post reads:

> John Doe shared Jane Doe's video: December 1, 2012 at 9:30pm.

...then you tap the date & time on the post -the "December 1, 2012 at 9:30pm" part- and it will take you to the video without using the expired link. The video should play that way.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced 'v' with 'embed' in url. It worked.

VideoUrl = VideoUrl.replace("/v/", "/embed/")