# When does Facebook video expire and can it be un-expired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm dealing with Facebook videos accessed from users' posts (they have given permission via an app) which I'm trying to play in an external page.

The video doesn't play, now. It may have done in the past.

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332200/fbcdn-an-error-occurred-while-processing-your-request) (I get the same error message) seems to indicate that external access to video via Facebook expires after a certain length of time, but I can't find any Facebook developer documentation about this. Is this to do with the `offline_access` permission?

Can anyone confirm how/when these videos expire, and how/if they can be made to play again?

The URLs break down like this, in case that helps:

```
http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-snc6/v/[6 digits]/[3 digits]/[13 digits]_[5 digits].mp4
?oh=[32 alphanumeric chars]
&oe=[8 alphanumeric chars]
&__gda__=[10 digits]_[32 alphanumeric chars]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that image and videos link can be expired overtime and you need to get the latest link for particular image or videos

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).